# Can I read from notes during an online PhD interview?

Tags: phd, interview

I am preparing for an online PhD interview soon.
I took notes about every possible question that the board would ask me during the interview.
My question is : is it totally fine if i had to read from those notes (to provide a detailed answer) during  the interview in order to answer their questions ?

Comment: Obviously, it depends on the question. For "easy" questions, you should have an answer ready by heart, for more difficult it is okay to look at your notes. But for most (probably all?) questions you should not read from your notes, just look at them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you answer without any kind of visual aid: you may come across as inauthentic or the interviewer might think you are cheating in some way. Just practice your answers a couple of times until you feel comfortable.

However, you can write down your own questions to your interviewer and read them when you will be asked if you have any questions. I reckon this is highly appreciated.